# python function return convention

Tags: python-2.7, pep8

what is the convention of python, for how many returns can a function have ? I want to split a big function into smaller ones.

For that reason I want to make one of the function like a setup function. That setup func will return all the parameters needed (around 10 parameters returned). Is there a convention for that, if so, is it okay with returning 10 parameters out of one function ?